# Potential malicious uses of javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Firefox 6, you can no longer put javascript in the address bar because of security risks such as recent scripts on facebook. I understand it can simulate just about anything you can click, like removing friends and spamming wall posts, but what's the absolute worst? It can only manipulate the page you're on because of cross-domain iframe javascript being disabled, unless it sends an XMLHttpRequest based on cookie data.

What exactly were the scripts on facebook doing that made it such a big problem? What's the worst that can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javascript can do anything you can do.

On Facebook, for example, it can manipulate friends and posts.

On World of Warcraft, it can give all of your money and items to whoever created the script.

On your bank (which is a little less likely since banks won't have posts asking people to run `javascript:` URLs), it can empty your bank account.

On any site, it could also create a fake login form within the site that sends your credentials to a malicious server.
A very clever malicious script could do that almost indetectably (by handling link clicks and using HTML5 address bar APIs)

Comment: I won't ask why you know the second bit.

Comment: @Walkerneo: I don't even play WoW.  However, Javascript can do _anything_ that you can (except type your password), so it could also give items.

Comment: Also, if you paste javascript into the URL while you're on a banking website, you deserve to have the account emptied

Comment: That's why I said it's less likely.

Comment: Thanks, the one about logins is true, I didn't think of it.

Comment: @Slaks type passwords? I have js do that for me on less important sites where logging in is more of a pain than a security measure.

Comment: @Joseph, it can type your password if it knows it; however, if the attacker is using this type of attack, presumably he does not have your password.

Comment: @Joseph: A malicious Javascript cannot type your password _because it doesn't know your password_.  That's (one reason) why you need to confirm your existing password before changing it.

Comment: @Slaks Yes, I know... in theory though, js could be key logger couldn't it?  Then it could learn your password. :P

Comment: @Joseph - not if you are typing into a password field and the logger is pure JS. let's face it, someone could create a mallicious browser that was exactly like Firefox. Anyone who used it thinking they were running Firefox could be open to **any** kind of attack. The trick is to get people to use it (i.e. so-called social engineering attacks) without realising what is going on.

Comment: @Joseph: Only if the user types a password on that page after the Javascript runs.  The JS can also just make its own login prompt, as I mentioned.

Comment: It actually sounds pretty easy to make one as a global userscript, which would solve the problem of it having to run before user input.  Actually it could even just look for password fields and save the values if there is already a value. If not, it could add a change event listener... the thing I don't get is why is the value property of password fields public anyway?  Shouldn't that be write only with js?

Comment: @Joseph: You can't trick a user into making a global uerscript.  Password fields are readable to allow AJAX logins or client-side hashing.

Comment: fascinating... the world of internet security and hacking is truly fascinating.  Thank you SLaks, RobG, and Michael for answering my silly questions. :)

Comment: @Joseph: You're welcome; it certainly is.  You may want to explore http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> It can only manipulate the page you're on because of cross-domain...

False. If the attacker can convince you to type a piece of JavaScript in the URL bar, they can probably also convince you to visit any page, as well. I imagine the worst possible scenario would be one where the attacker managed to grant him or herself additional privileges to exploit later or grabbing your contact list or personal details that could be used in a subsequent social engineering attack.

The bottom line, though, is that this sort of attack is able to run code with whatever level of authorization you currently have. So, if you are logged into a website, whatever you can do on that website, the attacker could do as well. In fact, this is one of the reasons that changing one's password or granting additional account access almost always asks the user to reauthenticate even if already logged-in. (Because the JavaScript won't be able to log-in for you, unless the attacker already has your credentials, which would make that sort of attack moot, anyway. So, this will prevent the attacker from invisibly giving him or herself additional credentials or changing your password to one under his/her control.)

Comment: It is (hopefully) much harder to convince a user to visit a URL, _then_ paste in Javascript.  Especially if that URL is a high-value target.

Comment: @SLaks, given how easy it is to convince users to install add-ons and extensions with excessive permissions, I imagine that convincing the user to visit a URL and then past a JavaScript URL would not be too challenging.

Answer (score 0):

What can be done by white/gray hat hackers:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-hack-your-facebook-account-with-greasemonkey-javascript/
http://userscripts.org/tags/facebook
http://www.hacktabs.com/facebook-javascript-codes/

What can be done by black hat hackers:
(have not tested just got from google) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-S5CVJ09nMg
I know in a CTF competition I was able to retrieve an accounts e-mail by embedding a script with an image, though it was a low level competition so the security was probably worse than facebook.

The interesting thing is it is nearly easier to make something that looks like facebook and social engineer people to log in there than to hack their actual facebook.  Also on the android you can make an invisible lair pop up on top of facebook to intercept passwords.  Disabling javascript doesn't fix much.

Answer (score 0):

The usual response is

> if people are stupid enough to run untrusted code on their computers,
>   they get what they deserve.

But people likely don't know that they are running untrusted code, or what it is capable of. Removing the javscript pseudo-protocol is a waste of time.

Better to educate users that scripts can be run from bookmarks and address bars and that such scripts have all the permissions they do as a user. And for browsers to distinguish whether an address bar script was typed, copy and pasted or from a bookmark and warn the user what is about to happen (much like the status bar tells you where a link is about to send you).

Comment: And how, exactly, do you intend to educate users?

Comment: It's like virtual survival of the fittest.

Comment: @SLaks — it's not my personal responsibility to educate users in general, however I do try to educate people in regard to basic internet security when I have the opportunity or think they will benefit. It is the responsibility of those with knowledge and experience to offer it to the community at large for its benefit — "for the greater good" and so on. :-)

Comment: Yes, but that's extremely difficult and probably impossible.

Comment: "extremely difficult and probably impossible" to do what? Educate users? How on earth do they survive?